# Não é possível usar isset () no resultado de uma expressão com PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress, if

Quero que quando meu site seja acessado com a referencia?ref=app mostre uma pagina, se não for aparecera outra.

Porem so da esse erro:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" 
instead) in D:\XAMP\htdocs\baixarmp3\wp-content\themes\b4-baixar-mp3\single.php on line 61
```

Meu código da linha 61:

```
if (isset($_GET["ref"] == "app")) {
```

Meu código completo:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["ref"] == "app")) {
        include ('single/single-app.php');
    }
    else {
        include ('single/single-site.php');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Porque você não faz `if ($_GET["ref"] == "app") {`? Não faz muito sentido verificar se um booleano (o resultado da expressão em questão) está definido. Uma expressão sempre estará "definida"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O método `isset()` apenas verifica se a variável possui ou não algum valor.

```
<?php

isset($a); // retorna false, pois $a não possui valor, ou seja, é null
$a = 3
isset($a); // retorna true, pois agora $a possui valor
```

Quanto ao seu código, há duas maneiras de fazer:

1º: removendo o `isset()`:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET["ref"] == "app")) {
        include ('single/single-app.php');
    } else {
        include ('single/single-site.php');
    }
?>
```

2º: adicionando o `isset()` como parâmetro de validação:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET["ref"]) && $_GET["ref"] == "app") {
        include ('single/single-app.php');
    } else {
        include ('single/single-site.php');
    }
?>
```

Ambos entregarão a mesma ideia: caso o parâmetro `ref` seja igual a `app`, incluirá `single-app.php`, caso contrário, estando `null` ou não, incluirá `single-site.php`.

Comment: Ainda estou com esse erro: Parse error: Unmatched ')' in D:\XAMP\htdocs\baixarmp3\wp-content\themes\b4-baixar-mp3\single.php on line 61

Print: https://prnt.sc/xdtfig 02: https://prnt.sc/xdtgbg

Comment: @MatheusVitor o `if()` possuía um parênteses a mais, tenta agora

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado.